# How to select all the rows from an entity with NSFetchedRequest or NSPredicate?

Tags: iphone, core-data, select, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I'm very very new to Core Data, and I'm still messed up with it and with all its possibilities.

I have a table USER in my model, and I'd like to obtain all the rows as an "SELECT * FROM USER".

Which is the best way to achieve that?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 15):

Use [NSPredicate predicateWithValue:YES] to select all.

Answer (score 6):

From the `NSFetchRequest` docs:

> If you don’t specify a predicate, then all instances of the specified entity are selected (subject to other constraints, see executeFetchRequest:error: for full details).

Answer (score 1):

The basic fetch operation goes like that:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:theEntityName inManagedObjectContext:_context];

NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest new];
[request setEntity:entity];
```

You can apply sorting using NSSortDescriptor at this stage.

Then you fetch all the entities:

```
NSError *error;    
NSMutableArray *fetchResults = [[_context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: in the fetchResults will be the entities objects, isn't it?

Comment: Correct! They are properly typed entities.